# Why does Typescript only infer this function's return type when the caller provides explicit generic type parameters?

Tags: typescript, generics

I've written a Typescript function which, given a relationship type, a direction, and a nominal nodeId, returns a list of nodes on the opposite end of that relationship. Eg

```
("A_TO_B", "from", "nodeAId") -> NodeB[]
```

Is it possible to type this function such that Typescript correctly narrows/infers the return type, without passing explicit type parameters?

Curiously in my current implementation, the inference does work if the caller explicitly passes the first two generic type parameters:

```js
export function getNeighborsByRelationship<
  T extends ExtractRelationshipsByNodeId<D>["type"],
  D extends Extract<keyof Relationship, "from" | "to"> = Extract<
    keyof Relationship,
    "from" | "to"
  >,
  R extends ExtractRelationshipByType<T> = ExtractRelationshipByType<T>,
  N extends Node = ExtractNodeById<
    R[Exclude<Extract<keyof R, "from" | "to">, D>]
  >
>(
  type: R["type"],
  dir: D,
  id: R[D]
): {
  nodes: N[];
  relationships: R[];
}

function test () {
  const id: AppleId = "A"
    
  // this does not infer the return type correctly... :(
  const res = getNeighborsByRelationship('APPLE_TO_CLOCK_AND_DOGGIE', 'from', id)

  // however, this does:
  // const res = getNeighborsByRelationship<'APPLE_TO_CLOCK_AND_DOGGIE', 'from'>('APPLE_TO_CLOCK_AND_DOGGIE', 'from', id)

  return res?.nodes[0].label
}
```

But I'm unable to make the inference work without explicitly passing the generic types.

My current work, reproducible and complete with sample Node and Relationship types, is included in the Playground link. The structure of Node and Relationship types is provided for convenience only, since they would not be easy to change in the codebase I'm working in.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgUABCEHIPYBMCmFkDMCWA7DAXDcWAzpCMGLgJ4AOKAgtdQDZICSCEAvBAER08UaKAEIBDImw7cewgVVoQAwkzgBjANbsuvRXKEQAInADmxjJO08DAwQobMU3AN4QMCAFwR7LdgBoITKIARkhMngDk3kjh-kRwALZIUQDKtKoYmKoACgBOcLQ5VJ64OQCuKAC+tiLijhAubp5iEn4BwaERzdGxCUhdqUjpmbn5SIWUxWWV1UoqGtoNHrNqmgj+gSFhEOHKKzEQcYm7GgNDGNl5BUUQJeUQVfIoRqbmC65Lz2aS6+1b4Z-mfaHJAApCnDLnEZXCY3Kb3MAzeDILTcKJaAA+EC6GOWGhxoPYiMQdSiEExXTJuPUlNBCLAoFIEAASqFRPhCEQABYYaioJCYHDs4ikciPLyMFgAFTgx3UdCwCFBbzQeXinjRaxucE8svxJi+rUenj4WSyABkAKIAfUlAHkrYozbbFABpK10GAGK0GW0AcV9rAtPHhYq60tlytVTVqhu1VMNQmNwjoyWtdodTtdwYe+lB0tJzggKoSngJmtwcY1-iNvB9-sDNvtdFNluzM1l0tB8oQFMLxbV8fLcbLlOx5cTOkzbvTdYD1o9XuTqbbMxZgSFXJ52ii4bmcoVSvJtV3Kxp+vM+YlKExHbgXYVXQRDKgEAAqvgmHhKDchCQoOQkAAD2oOBCh-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-ZyA3YKYShmpLiB3EFym-eIXyDew7h+sG4bRvG0T4eofnIhbNN7UdZ03QXb0-TnfZwn7fY3CVhFKYjiBOTgAB3JAADcxmraPUDjrXw8jqv3dr7QG5gIaRrGnIJrbpDO-NbuMz791PUH+sLRHseSI75tr8bW-XXvr1Z0DF+qpx4IEnj7DOWcnK1wAPzNQ1sgIguEAAMRFmobFCGAc2u9fJL20BhJqnsIAzzFNyLAvk0CgQgAAAyXpQg4c9ShMA4CEKhPBZQgysOeJAPBKFAA)

Comment: You'd need both [ms/TS#20216](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20126) and [ms/TS#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234) to get this working; TS cannot infer from `R` from `R[D]`, nor can it infer `T` from its constraint.  If you want better inference you need to make sure the function params are very directly related to the type params... maybe like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8gEPW) (here I'm just computing `T`, `N`, and `R` inline from other types, but you could use utility types if you want).

Comment: See prev comment.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes that does make sense, and your playground works as I'd hoped! The problem is, and I'm remembering I'd already tried this, the inline return declaration causes Typescript (v5.3.2) to error out `TS2590: Expression produces a union type that is too complex to represent` when compiled locally.

Comment: So then you have an XY problem? You had problem X (the typings with correct inference produced too-complex unions), tried to solve it with Y (adding extra generic type parameters) but had a problem (inference failed), so you asked about that.  I'm happy to write up my suggestion for Y as an answer.  You *could* make a big [edit] to the question to ask about X instead of Y, but then it's essentially like a new question.  You might get farther if you just keep this one as about Y and then open a new question about X.  But you're in charge of this question, more or less. How should we proceed?

Comment: @jcalz agreed. If you write an answer to this current question as currently stated, I'll accept it as the answer and start a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few limitations of TypeScript's type inference algorithm which are preventing this from working.

The first missing feature is described at [microsoft/TypeScript#20126](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/20126): TypeScript cannot infer a type `T` from an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `T[K]`.  Your `type` parameter is of type `R["type"]`, but because of this limitation, TypeScript cannot infer `R` from this.

The second missing feature is described at [microsoft/TypeScript#7234](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7234): TypeScript cannot infer a type `T` from a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) on another type parameter, like `U extends F<T>`.  Your `T` parameter is not mentioned anywhere inside the function parameters; it appears only as a constraint on `R`, so `T` cannot be inferred at all.

---

Until and unless these are addressed, you'll need to change your generic type parameters.  The general approach I suggest is to cut down to as few generic type parameters as possible (if you are using [default type arguments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) as shortcuts to using inline type computations, that might be acceptable, but for the first pass at this you should not use defaults for this purpose.  Either compute your types inline, or write utility types for them), and have your function parameters be of types as directly related to these type parameters as possible.  Like this:

```
declare function getNeighborsByRelationship<
  T extends Relationship["type"],
  D extends "from" | "to">(
    type: T,
    dir: D,
    id: ExtractRelationshipByType<T>[D]
  ): {
    nodes: (
      ExtractNodeById<ExtractRelationshipByType<T>[
        Exclude<Extract<keyof ExtractRelationshipByType<T>, "from" | "to">, D>
      ]>)[];
    relationships: ExtractRelationshipByType<T>[];
  }
```

Here we have only two generic type parameters; `T` corresponds exactly to the type of `type`, and `D` corresponds exactly to the type of `D`.  That means when you call the function, `T` and `D` should be inferrable from the first two function arguments.  And those two type parameters should be enough information to compute all the rest of the types you care about, such as the type of `id`, and the element types of the `nodes` and `relationships` property of the return value.

If that's too cluttered you could make utility types like

```
type N<R extends Relationship, D extends "from" | "to"> =
  ExtractNodeById<R[
    Exclude<Extract<keyof R, "from" | "to">, D>
  ]>;

declare function getNeighborsByRelationship<
  T extends Relationship["type"],
  D extends "from" | "to">(
    type: T,
    dir: D,
    id: ExtractRelationshipByType<T>[D]
  ): {
    nodes: N<ExtractRelationshipByType<T>, D>[];
    relationships: ExtractRelationshipByType<T>[];
  }
```

or use default type arguments, but that's out of scope here.

---

Anyway, let's just make sure it behaves as expected:

```
function test() {
  const id: AppleId = "A"
  const res = getNeighborsByRelationship('APPLE_TO_CLOCK_AND_DOGGIE', 'from', id)
  //    ^? const res: { 
  //         nodes: ExtractNodeById<"C" | "D">[]; 
  //         relationships: AppleToClockAndDoggie[]; 
  //       }
  return res?.nodes[0].label
}

const v = test()
//    ^? const v: "Clock" | "Doggie"
```

Looks good! Inference happened correctly and the types are as you expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAbzgXwFAHoBUq6bgOQgBNg4SAzASwDtKZKJqBnHTdVGATzFIEEwwAG2ABJInAC8cAES9pHbqQBCAQyajxU6UvlcecAMKCIAYwDWYyTIO7FcACIQA5k8oar0+-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-szB3pSOOnuSZqi7uIDj8a2IO3JaMKRhsLg4ABVeiCOicFGKFi4fk7CNEAGhUEwYExSZODEAAeYU4FAGBgElJgCGIYAAG1pGCaQAF0AD4rGA0DwJgyCYj+OB4OQfCAG4nwFYioDAmA1wZBhmFZMAlE4YVFDghCQOQohULYjcuKwto8MIqQmJYmCcFpelxLZKJFKQStqNQOinxIEw4igUhyEaahwI4uAnGACDgEoJxmXiaAmB4sSOM3MAFLgKjBKQlClPXVyJOkKTcLUzz7G84TUOkHtfXxIKIGkfCAApFM8zTQs8shKCgf4Ms8no4Dk8CXKZLieL4ng4PwjD7FwxSAEowgQVK4GodCmDCFLMsyoqIPQnjYN6krOLZcr+OFaqWu64D9MaEgYN6mCzGATgIHIQqQOY4rlIC0bePG-CYmi+VYpkFVEpiex8KmuACPqjDcPo7rDP80q2Q6jaSNYna3u4-bKomh6no+VBqBUPImDAMDSHKCAmCYSh4mED9KC-LgKtIZq0rsfAYJpCLfOGtzLoJkSZBiol4sSyQWt6yCBqIPGMJumbBDm4AFs2+TltW9aaSOim4vOw6HGu7qCPoxS9IMoyTLMxgLKs-AbLshyoCczgia4jzMvgxDIr89jfskxQ8LyhxSaiwWzoS5KbvSm6iGy3KboKoafpGv6Maqmq6u6xrEButqSA+3H3dez2xoBkWrqBm6XqNz2PvDxO3KjjnAcelr0XRKlX3sYAciZUCeT5VBjNMnkUWAJgYCS+rA88kxi+6XZyw8ORFOb5h4EM1CpEs6zbPsxznI9tykrSRtk0tSd7UdZ1XQ9OdLhSHtLmCerFPQdBuoAPQAfjgbva7gPums84Oa7COn+ugxnpBsSmvGqx6z-HriPvSU9zEPC8gY+J5QyMBGhQGoO-JgB8AB0V8mAYQAAy4SgUcJIqB0Qn3gAANysEhWu9cMC70yofY+LdMETn3KdTwF5vCoCAA)